# how to use jmeter to send data using a http request

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jmeter, playframework

I try to use Jmeter and a http request to send data to a controller using a function to create 5 new user with the same data.

Jmeter HttpRequest:
[image]

the function inside the controlleur:

```
public Result create(Http.Request request){
    var body = safeJsonBody(request);
    var mandatory_params = Ref.of(List.of("username", "firstname", "email", "password", "phonenumber", "address"));
    var maybeUsername = extractNonEmptyString(body, "username");
    var maybeFirstname = extractNonEmptyString(body, "firstname");
    var maybeEmail = extractEmail(body, "email");
    var maybePassword = extractNonEmptyString(body, "password");
    var hashedPassword = "";
    if(!maybePassword.isEmpty())
    {
        var hash = hashFactory.mkHash(maybePassword.get(), Registration);
        hashedPassword= hash.get().hash;
    }
    var maybePhonenumber = extractNonEmptyString(body, "phonenumber");
    var maybeAddress = extractNonEmptyString(body, "address");

    logger.warn("maybeUsername                           : " + maybeUsername);
    logger.warn("maybeFirstname                           : " + maybeFirstname);
    logger.warn("maybeEmail                           : " + maybeEmail);
    logger.warn("maybePassword                           : " + maybePassword);
    logger.warn("maybePhonenumber                           : " + maybePhonenumber);
    logger.warn("maybeAddress                               : "+maybeAddress);

    if ( maybeUsername.isEmpty() || maybeFirstname.isEmpty() || maybeEmail.isEmpty() || maybePassword.isEmpty()) {
        checkIfIsPresent(mandatory_params,maybeUsername,"username");
        checkIfIsPresent(mandatory_params,maybeFirstname,"firstname");
        checkIfIsPresent(mandatory_params,maybeEmail,"email");
        checkIfIsPresent(mandatory_params,maybePassword,"password");
        checkIfIsPresent(mandatory_params,maybePhonenumber,"phonenumber");
        checkIfIsPresent(mandatory_params,maybeAddress,"address");

        return badRequest("Missing mandatory params: " + mandatory_params);
    }


    var tx = usersModel.upsert(maybeUsername.get(),maybeFirstname.get(),
            maybeEmail.get(),hashedPassword,maybePhonenumber.get(),maybeAddress.get());
    if (tx.isEmpty()){
        logger.warn(tx.toString());
        return internalServerError(stc_map_to_json(Map.of("status","error","message", "The user could not be created or updated.")).get());
    }
    return ok(tx.get());
}
```

I see "Missing mandatory params: Ref{val=[username, firstname, email, password, phonenumber, address]}" inside the response body in the View result tree I created so the data must be going to the right function.

And I try display the content of the request send to the controller by using a logger and it's weirdly display "POST  /user/create"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to send a [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) structure like:

```
{
  "username": "userJM",
  "firstname": "usernameJM",
  "email": "userJM@gmail.com",
  "password": "mdpJM",
  "phonenumber": 12345678934,
  "address": "150 rue jmeter"
}
```

In JMeter it would be something like:

[image]

You might also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and configure it to send Content-Type header with the value of `application/json`

[image]

If you're not sure how to properly build this or that request the easiest way is just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)